# Razor .cshtml syntax highlighting for vim?

Tags: vim, razor, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a .cshtml vim syntax file.  Are there any projects that haven't made it to www.vim.org?

Comment: Interesting question. I would suppose that it's at least very difficult to do syntax highlighting without reproducing a lot of what razor does.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be a fairly involved syntax file, but there has to be a way to at least get an 80% solution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

":setf html" solves the 80% part :)

Comment: ya; i've been doing that, but I need to remember to not use my html tidy keyboard shortcut :)

Answer (score 8):

this guy has razor support planned, but is not yet there. However, it does add some features to the existing c# support.
https://github.com/OrangeT/vim-csharp

Comment: Razor syntax is there now.

Answer (score 6):

Settled with adding this to `.vimrc`

```
" add html syntax to dotnet razor files
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cshtml set syntax=html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find nice vim-razor plugin in https://github.com/adamclerk/vim-razor

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle
$ git clone https://github.com/adamclerk/vim-razor
```

Answer (score 1):

Russ Martinez  (or maybe Daniel Dabrowski's) cshtml.vim file seems to be a candidate. It's not perfect, but at least it's a start. https://bitbucket.org/rod/dotfiles/src/8aaae8635165/vim/syntax/cshtml.vim